# How can I obtain an image's PPI in JavaScript if it's unavailable in EXIF Data?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, exif, frappe

I have a tool in frappe-framework that permits image uploads by checking, the width[=1050px], height[=1500px] and filesize [between 300KB to 3000KB] of an image.
Along with the existing requirements I need to add an additional check to permit image upload if PPI = 300.
I am able to get the PPI using the EXIF metadata in javascript.

Is there an alternative approach or library I can use to get an image's PPI when it's not present in the EXIF data?

Comment: If PPI is not in the EXIF data, then there is no way to know.  It's just that simple.  It might be an animated image, in which case there is no PPI.

Comment: @Tim Roberts  is there any method to calculate the PPI from any of the other available parameters in EXIF data, if actual width and height in inches were available it would have been useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  PPI isn't meaningful for photos.  If I take a picture of an document on my desk, that's a very different physical size than if I take a picture of a  mountain in the distance.

Comment: @TimRoberts — Eh? The PPI has nothing to do with the real world size of the subject of the photo. It's a printing specification.

Comment: Your PPI requirement, frankly, seems **weird**. Why does it matter? If you're going to print the image at 3.5"×5" then just tell the user that.

Comment: Quentin -- yes, exactly.  That's the point.  The PPI of a photo is meaningless.  When you go to print it, then you resize the image based on the PPI you need.

Comment: Given two scenarios
Scenario 1
an image with 72 PPI
and when printed the size is 3.5 inches x 5 inches

Scenario 2
an image with 300 PPI
and when printed the size is 3.5 inches x 5 inches

the second scenario will definitely be a good print right.

@Quentin sometimes users will be uploading an image with 72 PPI and sometimes 300 ppi images, the point is while PPI is available in the exifdata the code works.
but as a backup measure i will need to apply some heuristic to calculate PPI from the available image attributes.

Comment: the images i use for testing is not having an exif data associated with it, but in paint application in windows  and mac preview it shows DPI in pixels per inch, file size, file height in pixels, file width in pixels.

the question is how do these tools get this info without an exif data, can i get the same info from javascript while the image is loaded.